# Disable query correction in google cse list api

Tags: google-custom-search

I am using Google's CSE list api for searching images over the web. The problem I am facing is that the search engine automatically corrects my query and provides results based on that.

For example When I search for "Gulla Ebong Gullar Ghora" it modifies the query to "Gullar Ebony Gullar Ghora". Can anyone suggest a solution to prevent this from happening.

Json response as under :-

```
"request": [
   {
    "title": "Google Custom Search - \"Gulla Ebong Gullar Ghora\"",
    "totalResults": "1",
    "searchTerms": "\"Gulla Ebong Gullar Ghora\"",
    "count": 1,
    "startIndex": 1,
    "inputEncoding": "utf8",
    "outputEncoding": "utf8",
    "safe": "off",
    "cx": "search engine id",
    "fileType": "jpg,jpeg",
    "searchType": "image",
    "imgSize": "large"
   }
  ]
 },
 "context": {
  "title": "search engine name"
 },
 "searchInformation": {
  "searchTime": 0.325941,
  "formattedSearchTime": "0.33",
  "totalResults": "1",
  "formattedTotalResults": "1"
 },
 "spelling": {
  "correctedQuery": "\"Gullar Ebony Gullar Ghora\"",
  "htmlCorrectedQuery": "&quot;\u003cb\u003e\u003ci\u003eGullar\u003c/i\u003e\u003c/b\u003e \u003cb\u003e\u003ci\u003eEbony\u003c/i\u003e\u003c/b\u003e Gullar Ghora&quot;"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting with "exactTerms" or "as_epq" parameter. Please see the api documentation for more info.